# Reading from socket blocks

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to read a response from a server. I have two methods.  The first one doesn't block but the second one does.   I don't understand why the difference..

Method 1:

```
public static String lireReponse() throws IOException, NullPointerException {
    // recepteurReponses is a BufferedInputStream
    String reponse = "";
    byte[] flux = new byte[1024];
    int i = recepteurReponses.read(flux);
    reponse += new String(flux, 0, i);
    return reponse;
}
```

Method 2:

```
public static String lireDonnees() throws IOException, NullPointerException {
    String reponse = "";
    byte[] flux = new byte[1024];
    int i = -1;
    while ((i = recepteurReponses.read(flux)) != -1)
        reponse += new String(flux, 0, i);
    return reponse;
}
```

Comment: Is `recepteurReponses` ever closed?

Comment: What makes me sure that the first method doesn't block is that the client get the answer and i can print it in the console.And yes the recepteurReponses is closed when the client send a CLOSE request to the serveur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first method performs a single read, fails to check for end of stream, and returns the data read as a String, or in the case of end of stream throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

The second method reads in a loop until end of stream occurs and then returns all the data read as a single string.

End of stream occurs when the peer closes the connection. If the peer doesn't close the connection, the second method will block in the read method.

Comment: :O i see i understand now why it blocks, i used the second method to read a big amount of data, without closing the connection.
Oki, so tell me how to read a big amount of data, like a text or a message, which contains many lines without closing the connection ?

Comment: You'll have to send the length or line count ahead of the lines, or use a self-describing protocol like XML.

Comment: Thanks for the answers (y) :)